# Are wind waves in a body of water different to disturbance waves?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, waves, water

This is something I have been wondering about since I have been thinking about tsunami.  If you blow air across water it forms waves, if you throw a stone into water it also forms waves.

What I am curious is if you see waves and you don't know what the source of the wave was is there anything about the wave that would tell you about what caused it.